# Number of orbits of projective action

Tags: extension-field, group-actions, projective-space

let $L/K$ be a finite field extension (if you want, assume $K=\mathbf Q_p$).
Do we know the number of orbits of the action of ${\rm GL}_2(K)$ on the projective line $\mathbf P^1 (L)$ ?
If $L/K$ is quadratic, then it is obviously $2$.
What in general ?

Comment: I noted that the stabilizer of an element $z \in L$ is $K^\times \subset {\rm GL}_2(K)$ if and only if $z$ is not of degree $\le 2$ above $K$.